# window.open tamanho e lugar

Tags: javascript

estou usando o windows.open para abrir queria que ele abrisse igual um do popads no canto de baixo do lado direito e resolvir usar o codigo tal mas ele n diminui de tamanho e n fica no cando direito igual alguem poderia me ajudar segue o codico q usei

```
<script>
document.onclick = function(e){
    myFunction();
}

function myFunction(){
    window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=false, scrollbars=false,resizable=false, top=900, left=5000, width=300, height=4%");
    document.onclick = null; // anulando na próxima execução.
}
</script>
```

[image: Imagem de colo queria e n estou conseguindo]

Comment: não entendi nada

Comment: quando uso o codigo a cima ele abre uma janela e um tamanho mas n fica igual esse da ft q fica bem no canto direito e bem pequeno e queria que ficasse igual

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito mal formatada. Dê uma melhorada no português e acentuação para compreendermos o que você quer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não use valores em `%` no tamanho do *popup* porque o método [não suporta](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). Use apenas valores em pixels (sem o `px`).

Assumindo uma *popup* de 300x200, para abrir no canto inferior direito, use como base de cálculo as dimensões da janela diminuindo os valores pelo tamanho da *popup* no `top` e no `left`:

```
document.onclick = function(e){
   myFunction();
}

function myFunction(){

   var lar_janela = window.innerWidth;
   var alt_janela = window.innerHeight;

   console.log(alt_janela);
   window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=false, scrollbars=false,resizable=false, top="+(alt_janela-200)+", left="+(lar_janela-300)+", width=300, height=200");
   document.onclick = null; // anulando na próxima execução.
}
```